# Getting element mass in Abaqus postprocessor

Tags: abaqus

I want to hide all elements in my model with mass less than a value. Is it possible? 
I found only way to see mass of elements by creating set for each element in History Output, but it sounds stupid because the number of elements.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a display group based on the currently displayed field output variable. Element mass isn't available, but element volume is. (you have to request EVOL as an output before running the analysis). you should already know the density.

You should display the elements above your threshold volume. Then create a display group by selecting the elements currently visible in the viewport. This will ensure that you can then plot other field outputs while keeping the same elements displayed.

Comment: Probltm is that EVOL parameter for all elements are constant. There is - density changes. So it is not the option.

Comment: I don't understand how volume can remain constant but the mass can change? The only way for that to happen is to add mass to the system somehow?

Comment: Why do you think volume stays constant?