# Get material name for node

Tags: python, abaqus

I am doing some scripting for the first time for my customer right now, and extracting data from abaqus processed files. I got a question which I somehow cant solve myself after a few days, which is however probably trivial for experts.

The question is - I have a node object, and I have to get a name of material for this node (or its corresponding fieldoutput). How to do it?

Node looks like this:

({'baseElementType': '', 'conjugateData': None, 'conjugateDataDouble': 'unknown', 'data': array([4.12822773796506e-05, -0.000217618362512439, -0.00143215747084469], 'f'), 'dataDouble': 'unknown', 'elementLabel': None, 'face': None, 'instance': 'OdbInstance object', 'integrationPoint': None, 'inv3': None, 'localCoordSystem': None, 'localCoordSystemDouble': 'unknown', 'magnitude': 0.0014491849578917, 'maxInPlanePrincipal': None, 'maxPrincipal': None, 'midPrincipal': None, 'minInPlanePrincipal': None, 'minPrincipal': None, 'mises': None, 'nodeLabel': 510000010, 'outOfPlanePrincipal': None, 'position': NODAL, 'precision': SINGLE_PRECISION, 'press': None, 'sectionPoint': None, 'tresca': None, 'type': VECTOR})

Comment: Materials aren't applied to nodes, they're applied to elements. More specifically, they're applied to Sections, which are assigned to sets of elements through the `sectionAssignment` attribute of a `Part` object.

Comment: Thanks, I can get the section from the section assignment, but the problem is for me, that I am still probably too silly to find the material name from the section.... Section looks like this: ({'offset': 0.0, 'region': 'OdbSet object', 'sectionName': 'Section-P510001;HAG_SOLID_X7705669'})... I am coming heavily from .NET area, and would be searching for something like Something.getMaterial()

Comment: I wrote another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346825/getting-element-density-from-abaqus-output-database-using-python-scripting/49367901#49367901) to extract the density property off elements of certain materials. You can adapt it quite easily to your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up looping through all sections of the odb, making map of section name-material (for all sections with "material" property), and using it when necessary